# Place a textbox over an image in Microsoft Reports

Tags: c#, textbox, alignment, microsoft-reporting

I want to place a textbox over a non-background image in an rdlc report (Microsoft Reports C# .Net).
I do it in my designer and everything looks great.
I export a pdf from the ReportViewer object and it looks great.
But when I show the ReportViewer object in a form, I get a misalligned textbox. It doesn't stay over the image, but gets alligned on the right of the image.
I am posting screenshots:

1. ReportViewer designer in Visual Studio
   [image]
2. ReportViewer in a form (Notice the textbox value, number 4, on the right)
   [image]
3. PDF export
   [image]

**Why is the textbox misalligned in the ReportViewer and how can I fix it?**

Comment: What do you mean misaligned ? It seems fine to me...

Comment: Do you see the number 4 in the second screenshot? It should appear in the first box under A-1. See number 4 in the first and third screenshot and you will understand the problem.

Comment: I am sorry but all three pictures look same to me, I am looking at the box where '4' is written in the 1st picture than looking at other screen and they seem similar :P

Comment: In the second image the number four is far right, it doesn't even lie on the picture. It is quite obvious. I don't understand why you miss it?

Comment: Oh I see it now, I did not see that because I was not looking that far... I was trying to find it in the boxes :P

Comment: Is it being displayed outside the ReportViewer?

Comment: No, it lies in the ReportViewer and in the correct position regarding Y, but not regarding X. It lies just on the right of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Reportviewer renders using html that doesn't allow for overlapping objects that's why it looks right in a pdf but not on the reportviewer itself.